# .NET thread vanished

Tags: asp.net, .net, multithreading

I have dump of w3wp process (taken by procdump) where I see strange situation.

Simplified version on my code:

```
logger.Log(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
using(semaphore_release_on_dispose_object)
{
  // some third party code with unmanaged parts
  DangerousCode();
}
```

semaphore_release_on_dispose_object - release semaphore in Dispose.

Process dump was taken after some timeout, when it was clear that semaphore was not released

I found thread in dump, but it seems become 'bad'. It listed by `~` command, but not listed by `!threads` command. When I switch to it I can see unmanaged stack, but not managed:

```
0:004> ~
...
   3  Id: 63ec.11b0 Suspend: 1 Teb: 000007ff`fffae000 Unfrozen
...
0:004> ~~[11b0]s
ntdll!NtRemoveIoCompletion+0xa:
00000000`76e913aa c3              ret
0:003> k
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 00000000`01a3f818 000007fe`fcea169d ntdll!NtRemoveIoCompletion+0xa
01 00000000`01a3f820 00000000`76d2a4e1 KERNELBASE!GetQueuedCompletionStatus+0x39
02 00000000`01a3f880 000007fe`f0311f7b kernel32!GetQueuedCompletionStatusStub+0x11
03 00000000`01a3f8c0 000007fe`f0312024 w3tp!THREAD_POOL_DATA::ThreadPoolThread+0x3b
04 00000000`01a3f910 000007fe`f03120a1 w3tp!THREAD_POOL_DATA::ThreadPoolThread+0x34
05 00000000`01a3f940 00000000`76d3652d w3tp!THREAD_MANAGER::ThreadManagerThread+0x61
06 00000000`01a3f970 00000000`76e6c521 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
07 00000000`01a3f9a0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
0:003> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x11b0 (3)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
GetFrameContext failed: 1
0000000000000000 0000000000000000
```

So, I assume that somehow third party code some how 'broke' thread and skip finally block (using).

Any ideas how it is possible?